# Blender Object into threejs web

Tags: javascript, deployment, three.js, 3d, blender

I designed a keyboard in blender and seperated all of the keys and the base of the keyboard,after that i gave custom id to them and exported in a one file and opened in three js website.after that i got one by one key with the key that i gave in blender but when i hover on one key some keys are also changing colors , could you please give me a solution to this

I tried to change the color of the specific key when hovering the mouse.

```
//-----------------Raycaster(Object Selection)---------------------------------
const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

function onMouseMove(event) {
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

  const highlightedMaterials = []; // Store highlighted materials

  scene.traverse(function (object) {
    if (object.isMesh) {
      object.material.opacity = 1;
      object.material.transparent = true;

      // Reset color of all keys
      if (object.userData.keyID) {
        object.material.color.set(0xffffff); // Set desired color for keys
      }
    }
  });

  const intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, true);

  intersects.forEach(function (intersect) {
    if (intersect.object.isMesh) {
      const intersectedKeyID = intersect.object.userData.keyID;
      const material = intersect.object.material;

      

      if (!highlightedMaterials.includes(material)) {
        // Change color of specific keys with unique materials
        for(var i=1;i<100;i++){
          if (intersectedKeyID == i) {
            intersect.object.material.color.set(0xff0000);
            highlightedMaterials.push(material);
            console.log(intersectedKeyID)
          } 
          
        }


        // Add more conditions for other keys as needed
      }
    }
  });
}


window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
//--------------------------------------------------
```

this is the code but when i hover multiple keys are changing color help me with this issue